# Mercury compilation error with Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: gcc, mercury

I've got a problem compiling Mercury on my Mac. I'm running Mac OS X 10.8, got Xcode 4.5 installed and also Command Line Tools.

What have I done so far:

I downloaded the tar.gz file, extracted it, run `./configure` in that folder, then used `make PARALLEL=-j2 install` command(as it said after `./configure`).

At that step I get the following in my command line:

```
MMAKE_DIR=`pwd`/scripts scripts/mmake  MMAKEFLAGS=-j2 DESTDIR= install
cd scripts && PATH=../scripts:../util:$PATH MMAKE_VPATH=. MMAKE_DIR=../scripts DESTDIR= ../scripts/mmake -j2
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `default_target'.
cd util && PATH=../scripts:../util:$PATH MMAKE_VPATH=. MMAKE_DIR=../scripts DESTDIR= ../scripts/mmake -j2 mfiltercc
make[2]: `mfiltercc' is up to date.
gc_grade=`scripts/ml --grade none.gc --print-gc-grade`; \
    cd boehm_gc && PATH=../scripts:../util:$PATH MMAKE_VPATH=. MMAKE_DIR=../scripts DESTDIR= ../scripts/mmake -j2 GC_GRADE=$gc_grade
MAKEFLAGS=""; export MAKEFLAGS; \
    PATH=../util:$PATH make -j2 -j1 \
        GRADE=none.gc GC_GRADE=gc \
        AR=ar RANLIB=ranlib \
        libgc.a libgc.dylib \
        FINAL_INSTALL_MERC_GC_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/mercury-11.07.2/lib/mercury/lib \
        dylib
make[3]: `libgc.a' is up to date.
make[3]: `libgc.dylib' is up to date.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `dylib'.
cd runtime && PATH=../scripts:../util:$PATH MMAKE_VPATH=. MMAKE_DIR=../scripts DESTDIR= ../scripts/mmake -j2
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `default_target'.
cd util && PATH=../scripts:../util:$PATH MMAKE_VPATH=. MMAKE_DIR=../scripts DESTDIR= ../scripts/mmake -j2
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `default_target'.
cd robdd && PATH=../scripts:../util:$PATH MMAKE_VPATH=. MMAKE_DIR=../scripts DESTDIR= ../scripts/mmake -j2
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `default_target'.
cd library && PATH=../scripts:../util:$PATH MMAKE_VPATH=. MMAKE_DIR=../scripts DESTDIR= ../scripts/mmake -j2
../scripts/mgnuc --grade none.gc        --       -c tree234.c -o tree234.o
../scripts/mgnuc --grade none.gc        --       -c array.c -o array.o
tree234.c:619: error: initializer element is not constant
tree234.c:619: error: (near initialization for ‘mercury_common_1[0].f2’)
tree234.c:623: error: initializer element is not constant
tree234.c:623: error: (near initialization for ‘mercury_common_1[1].f2’)
tree234.c:631: error: initializer element is not constant
tree234.c:631: error: (near initialization for ‘mercury_common_1[3].f2’)
tree234.c:640: error: initializer element is not constant
tree234.c:640: error: (near initialization for ‘mercury_common_2[0].f1[1]’)
tree234.c:646: error: initializer element is not constant
tree234.c:646: error: (near initialization for ‘mercury_common_2[1].f1[1]’)
tree234.c:652: error: initializer element is not constant
tree234.c:652: error: (near initialization for ‘mercury_common_2[2].f1[1]’)
tree234.c:658: error: initializer element is not constant
tree234.c:658: error: (near initialization for ‘mercury_common_2[3].f1[1]’)
array.c:681: error: initializer element is not constant
array.c:681: error: (near initialization for ‘mercury_common_1[0].f1[1]’)
array.c:699: error: initializer element is not constant
array.c:699: error: (near initialization for ‘mercury_common_1[3].f1[1]’)
array.c:715: error: initializer element is not constant
array.c:715: error: (near initialization for ‘mercury_common_1[6].f1[0]’)
array.c:717: error: initializer element is not constant
array.c:717: error: (near initialization for ‘mercury_common_1[6].f1[1]’)
array.c:729: error: initializer element is not constant
array.c:729: error: (near initialization for ‘mercury_common_1[8].f1[1]’)
array.c:754: error: initializer element is not constant
array.c:754: error: (near initialization for ‘mercury_common_2[1].f2’)
array.c:758: error: initializer element is not constant
array.c:758: error: (near initialization for ‘mercury_common_2[2].f2’)
array.c:762: error: initializer element is not constant
array.c:762: error: (near initialization for ‘mercury_common_2[3].f2’)
make[2]: *** [array.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [tree234.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [library] Error 2
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Then I read through the readme and it said that I should use the other version of `GCC`. So I installed these `Command Line Tools`(as I found that they do include GCC) and tried again. No luck, still the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may need to specify which C compiler to use with an environment variable before you run configure.  I'm not sure though as I don't use OS X.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the main maintainer of OS X port for Mercury.  With XCode 4.*, the executable
named gcc is not really gcc, it's actually a symlink for llvm-gcc.  llvm-gcc is buggy
and cannot compile the C code generated by the Mercury compiler -- we've checked, the
C code in question is valid C and both (real) gcc and clang have no trouble with it.

If you're using Mac OS X 10.7 or 10.8 I would **strongly** recommend using clang as
the C compiler for Mercury.
(See the file README.clang in the distribution for details.)  Alternatively, you could
install a real version of gcc (e.g from macports) and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm having the exact same problem.

I'll keep you posted, I think I just figured it out.
Funny though cause I did the exact same steps as you did.
I'm planning to install the new gcc and select that one to compile.

Probably a KULeuven student as well :) ?

-- Edit:

Looks like I just fixed it, I downloaded gcc 4.3, installed it.
Added this to ~/.profile:

> export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

ran `source ~/.profile` and tried make again, it's still installing.
It's been running for 4 mins now so I'm guessing I'm out of the woods,
last time it took me 5 secs to hit an error.